Ownable: Inheritance vs. Modifier for Gas Efficiency
When implementing access control in Solidity contracts, OpenZeppelin's Ownable library offers a convenient solution. However, a question arises regarding gas optimization: is it more gas-efficient to inherit the entire Ownable library or simply use the onlyOwner modifier?

In terms of gas efficiency, using the onlyOwner modifier is generally more efficient than inheriting the entire Ownable library, because modifiers add minimal overhead compared to library inheritance, which involves deploying and referencing additional contract code.
